# how to separate two rows in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of Neighborhood of Toronto, there is some cases when you fin two or three neighborhoods in the same box so the same row ( for the same borough) i want to separate them to two rows how to do it Please !
I am using pandas.
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. Can you show a sample of input data and output df?

Comment: my box is like that : [Regent Park , Harbourfront]  i want to separate them to two lines one for Rgenet Park and another one for Harbourfront

Comment: It is really hard to define a solution if there is no sample data, please provide on the de description a couple of records and the expected output, also make sure is the data you have in pandas, not typed data as the solution might not work. Use `df.head().to_clipboard()` so the data is copied, paste that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really flesh out this question with an example of your expected input and output, but I think you want something like this using [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    city=['Seattle'],
    hood=[['SoDo', 'Maple Leaf', 'View Ridge', 'North Gate', 'SLU']],
))

print('df before exploding:\n', df)

df = df.explode('hood')

print('\ndf after exploding:\n', df)
```

Output:

```
df before exploding:
       city                                             hood
0  Seattle  [SoDo, Maple Leaf, View Ridge, North Gate, SLU]

df after exploding:
       city        hood
0  Seattle        SoDo
0  Seattle  Maple Leaf
0  Seattle  View Ridge
0  Seattle  North Gate
0  Seattle         SLU

Process finished with exit code 0
```

EDIT: OP responded:

> yes it is exactly what i want but i have just a problem m box is like that : df before exploding: hood =[' SoDo, Maple Leaf, View Ridge, North Gate, SLU '] so i tried with explod but it is not possible because the , is a string charachter

If that is the case and it is just a single string then and the following extra step:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    city=['Seattle'],
    hood=[['SoDo, Maple Leaf, View Ridge, North Gate, SLU']],
))
print('df before exploding:\n', df)

df['hood'] = df['hood'].apply(lambda x: x[0].split(', '))
print('\ndf after splitting string in list:\n',df)

df = df.explode('hood')
print('\ndf after exploding:\n', df)
```

Output:

```
df before exploding:
       city                                             hood
0  Seattle  [SoDo, Maple Leaf, View Ridge, North Gate, SLU]

df after splitting string in list:
       city                                             hood
0  Seattle  [SoDo, Maple Leaf, View Ridge, North Gate, SLU]

df after exploding:
       city        hood
0  Seattle        SoDo
0  Seattle  Maple Leaf
0  Seattle  View Ridge
0  Seattle  North Gate
0  Seattle         SLU

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: yes it is exactly what i want but i have just a problem m box is like that :                                       df before exploding:
   hood  =[' SoDo, Maple Leaf, View Ridge, North Gate, SLU ']                                                          so i tried with explod but it is not possible because the , is a string charachter

Comment: edited my answer with a possible solution using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a little `lambda` function.

Comment: Yes, all right thank you so much for your help .